# jQuery Detect Select Even if First Option

Tags: jquery

I have a select set like this:

```
<select>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

And want to detect when a choice is made, even if it is option #1.  The problem I'm running into now is that .change does not see it as a change if option one is selected, but I'd like it to.  Anything that would help me?

Comment: This can be solved really easy reading the Jquery Documentation. Did you have any attemp of code?

Comment: add a default empty option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to trigger the `change` event when the page loads as follows.

**NOTE**: When the page loads, the default (selected) value, is `1`, but your `change` event handler will not fire. Yet if you change the value to `2`(*change event would fire*) and then back to `1`, the `change` event handler should fire now. To avoid having to do that, you trigger the `change` event when the page loads so that the event handler would fire with the default value.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value )
})
.change(); //<<<<<===== This does the trick!!
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: With the power of JQuery I can't understand why do this trick instead reading the value of the option directly.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in other way, that user has other event to check his value